# fgets() doesn't work after popen()

Tags: c, fork, vlc, popen, fgets

I am trying to start 'vlc' from a c program using system() command. After the command is executed, I am executing popen() and fgets() functions to get the PID of the vlc application already started. But the fgets() does not give the PID. The code is given below. It is running from 'root'. The vlc is started from another user account named 'sam', since vlc cannot be started from root.

```
char arrcCommand[2048] = {0};
char arrcGetPIDCommand[1024] = {0};
char arrcPID[1024] = {0};
int iStatus = 0;

/*User 'sam' was added previously*/
sprintf (arrcCommand, "sudo -u sam vlc -q -I dummy /media/video.mp4 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=16,fps=1,scale=Auto,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:rtp{dst=232.0.0.1,port=927,mux=ts,ttl=1}' >/dev/null 2>&1 &");

iStatus = system(arrcCommand);

sprintf(arrcGetPIDCommand, "sudo -u sam ps axu | grep vlc | grep port=927 | grep -v sudo | awk '{print $2}'");
FILE* pFp = popen(arrcGetPIDCommand, "r");
if(pFp == NULL)
{
    return -1;
}
if( fgets(arrcPID, sizeof(arrcPID), pFp) != NULL )
{
    printf("\n%d\n", atoi(arrcPID));
} 
else
{
    iRetVal = -1;
    return iRetVal;
}

pclose(pFp);
```

Note: This code snippet is working fine in a solo c program. But its not working in my actual codebase which is quite big and where other popen() functions are also called many times. I am not able to understand the problem. Please help me.

Comment: Oh my deity, that is a complicated way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Why don't you use `fork()` and `execvp()`? The parent process will know what its child process is directly; you can do the I/O redirection in the child; you don't need the `ps` command etc at all, nor pipes etc.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand it properly. In this way, I will get pid of the child process. But how to get pid of the vlc application? Can you please explain it little?

Answer (score 1):

You can make life easier if you just add `echo $!` to your `system` command which will print the background process PID, then you don't need to grep for it.  Of course this means using `popen()` for that command instead, to read the PID.

Comment: Sorry, I could not get it. Can you please provide an example?

Comment: `popen("sudo -u sam vlc ... &; echo $!")` then read from the pipe to get the background PID.  No more `system()`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried, but that gives syntax error:
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
The syntax error is also there if you fire the command in normal command line.

Comment: I apologize, the `;` should not be added.  Just `"sudo -u sam vlc ... & echo $!"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works perfectly. I fixed my problem too. The problem was occurring while I was debugging it with gdb. Probably the read buffer was used by gdb. Normally it works perfectly.